# Does MultiSearchRequest request returns response in the same sequence as it was added in SearchRequest?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using `MultiSearchRequest` to execute multiple search queries using `SearchRequest` as below:

```
MultiSearchRequest request = new MultiSearchRequest();

SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(IndexName.MYINDEX.getValue());
searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder); 
request.add(searchRequest);//Mutliple search queries are added here in a loop.
```

My question is when i call:

`MultiSearchResponse response = client.msearch(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`

can i expect to get response in the same sequence as the requests were added OR they will be at random. Currently i am assuming it will be returning response in sequence as they were added but in PARALLEL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search-api-response-body) in short **YES**

**Response body**

> (array) Includes the search response and status code for each search request matching **its order in the original multi search request**. If there was a complete failure for a specific search request, an object with error message and corresponding status code will be returned in place of the actual search response.